# Android break up zipping of large files

Tags: android

I am using the following code snippet to zip a directory:

http://www.jondev.net/articles/Zipping_Files_with_Android_(Programmatically)

I noticed that if the directory is big like >3MB. The created zip file is corrupted and I could not open it. It throws `"Archive is in unknown format or corrupted."` error in Windows.

Any idea how I can prevent this? For example if too big, then just zip till the threshold is reached. Or is there any other method?